# How to map list of objects to dictionary or map?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a `childDict` for later usage. I'm not just *trying* actually, I am succeeding.

This **works**:

```js
const childDict = new Map(
  this.voteCards.toArray().map(card => {
    return [card.placeInfo.id, card.placeInfo];
  })
);
```

However, the interpreter is not happy. I'll spare you the error message which is just a type conflict.

[image]

So how can I map a list to a dictionary or map?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `JSON.stringify(this.voteCards.toArray())` so we can see what each `card` looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to convert array of Objects to a dictionary in one line:

```
var voteCardsArray = [
    { placeInfo: { id: 42, desc: 'stuff 42' } },
    { placeInfo: { id: 65, desc: 'stuff 65' } },
    { placeInfo: { id: 89, desc: 'stuff 89' } },
];

var res = Object.assign({}, ...voteCardsArray.map(card => ({[card.placeInfo.id]: card.placeInfo})));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript isn't so good with tuples. Someone else noticed this problem and filed a bug [8936](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8936) but it was closed with

> tuple types are never inferred without a contextual type.

So you can avoid this type error by using `map.set()` instead.

```js
var voteCardsArray = [
    { placeInfo: { id: 42, desc: 'stuff 42' } },
    { placeInfo: { id: 65, desc: 'stuff 65' } },
    { placeInfo: { id: 89, desc: 'stuff 89' } },
];

const childDict = new Map();

for (let card of voteCardsArray) {
    childDict.set(card.placeInfo.id, card.placeInfo);
}

// Example usage
const card42 = childDict.get(42);
console.log(card42);
```

Comment: Fair enough. I was actually hoping for something that does not require an extra for loop :D

Comment: When you call array.map() you are performing a loop so there's no performance hit when compared to a for loop. Actually it performs better because the Map constructor likely loops anyway to convert the array-of-arrays into a map structure. So your original post is probably doing 2 loops instead of 1. See [this jsperf](https://jsperf.com/map-constructor-vs-loop-map-set/1) to measure performance.

Comment: Well performance is not an issue here it's just readability I was looking out for :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` types are defined here (for me) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L12

This is with these `lib` settings from tsconfig.json:

```
"lib": [
  "es2016",
  "es2017.intl",
  "es2017.object",
  "es2017.string",
  "es2017.typedarrays",
  "esnext.asynciterable",
  "dom"
]
```

The issue for you might be that the stuff returned from your `map` function isn't a ReadOnly array.